# Fetch posts by category with bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, bookshelf.js

I'm using bookshelf.js as my ORM for node. I have 2 models

```
Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'posts',
  categories: function () {
      return this.belongsToMany('Category');
  }
});

Category = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'categories',
  posts: function () {
     return this.belongsToMany('Post');
  }
});
```

They are related via categories_posts table, so its a many to many relationship.

Now I want the user to be able to view all posts in certain category. But I dont want just all posts, I want pagination. But I'm unable to fetch the total posts under specific category, it always returns the total posts that exists in the system.

I've tried this `Category.forge({id: id}).posts().query().count('*').then(function(total) {});` but total equals the total posts in `posts` table as opposed to total posts under category identified by `id`. Is this even possible, or I should make a helper method that directly queries the `categories_posts` table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution.

```
Category.forge({id: id}).fetch({withRelated: [{posts: function(q) {
    q.count('* AS count');
}}]})
.then(function(total) {
    console.log(total.toJSON().posts[0].count);
});
```

Will give the correct value of posts under category identified by `id`.